# Code unable to reconcile vector assignment

Tags: matlab

I am interested in modifying the code below to find the parameters `I_1`, `I_2`, `I_3` and `I_4`, to be used in another code. Every time I run the code, it throws up

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

on this line " mult(mult == 0) = B;".

I have spent eternity figuring out what the problem could be. Here is the code:

```
%%% Some Parameters %%
delta = 0.6; % Blanked subframe ratio
    B = [0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1]; %Power splitting factor
    k = 2.3; %Macro BS density
    f = k*5;  %Small cell density
    j = 300;  %users density  
  P_m = 46;   %Macro BS transmission power
  P_s = 23;   %SC transmit power
   Zm = -15;
   Zs = -15;

iter = 30; %Iteration run
   h = 500;  %Simulation area
  hu = 0.8*h;  %users simulation area
   Vm = round(k*h);  %Macro BS average no in h
   Vs = round(f*h);  %SC average no in h
   Vu = round(j*hu); %%users average no in hu
  Pm = 10^(P_m/10)/1000*10^(Zm/10);
  Ps = 10^(P_s/10)/1000*10^(Zs/10);

 for i = iter;
    %% XY coodinates for Macrocell, small cells and users.
    Xm = sqrt(h)*(rand(Vm,1)-0.5);      
    Ym = sqrt(h)*(rand(Vm,1)-0.5);      
    Xs = sqrt(h)*(rand(Vs,1)-0.5);      
    Ys = sqrt(h)*(rand(Vs,1)-0.5);      
    Xu = sqrt(hu)*(rand(Vu,1)-0.5);   
    Yu = sqrt(hu)*(rand(Vu,1)-0.5);

    %Total coordinates for MBS and small cells
    Total_Coord = [Xs Ys ones(size(Xs)) Xm Ym 2*ones(size(Xm))]; 

   %Distance between BSs and users
   [Xsm_mat, Xu_mat] = meshgrid(Total_Coord(:,1),Xu);
   [Ysm_mat, Yu_mat] = meshgrid(Total_Coord(:,2),Yu);
   Distance = sqrt((Xsm_mat-Xu_mat).^2 + (Ysm_mat-Yu_mat).^2);

   %% To determine serving BS for each user
   [D_m,idx_m] = min(Distance(:,(length(Xs)+1):end),[],2);
   idx_m = idx_m + length(Xs);
   [D_s,idx_s] = min(Distance(:,1:length(Xs)),[],2);

   %% Power received by users from each BS
   Psm_mat = [Ps*ones(length(Xu),length(Xs)) 
   Pm*ones(length(Xu),length(Xm))]; % Transmit power of MBS and small cells
   Pr_n = Psm_mat.*exprnd(1,size(Psm_mat))./(Distance*1e3).^4; 
   mult = binornd(1,delta,1,length(Xm)); % Full transmission power of each 
   interfering MBS for delta
   mult(mult == 0) = B; % Reduced transmission power for (1-delta)
   Pr = Pr_n.*[ones(length(Xu),length(Xs)) repmat(mult,length(Xu),1)];% 
   Interference from each BS

   %% Power received by each user from serving BSs
   Prm = Pr(sub2ind(size(Pr),(1:length(idx_m))',idx_m));
   Prs = Pr(sub2ind(size(Pr),(1:length(idx_s))',idx_s));
   P_m_n = Pr_n(sub2ind(size(Pr_n),(1:length(idx_m))',idx_m));

   %% Total interference for each UE
   I_T = sum(Pr,2) - Prm - Prs;

   I_1 = P_m_n./(Prs + I_T); 
   I_2 = Prs./(P_m_n + I_T);
   I_3 = B*I_1;
   I_4 = Prs./(B*P_m_n + I_T);
end
```

The error appeared on this line "mult(mult == 0) = B;".

I know it to be assignment problem which requires equality in both the left and right dimensions. Suggestions for correction will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't even go until your line... for me it stops at `Total_Coord = [Xs Ys ones(size(Xs)) Xm Ym 2*ones(size(Xm))];` with error **Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.**.

Comment: Thanks @Bebs. Looking into the parameters, how can I modify the code to make it produce the required output? I've found my ways around so many tricks with no success. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to help you, but I didn't have the same error message as you even I just copied exactly your code. Your question has a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector `mult` has length `Vm` (number of macro BS?). Assigning to `mult(mult==0)` will assign to a subset of this vector (those that have a value equal to zero). What you are assigning is your variable `B` which you define as `B = [0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1]`, i.e., it is a length-6 vector. The assignment fails unless `mult` has exactly 6 zeros.

I highly doubt that this is what you want. It looks like you are trying to assign the same value ("Reduced transmission power"). Then your `B` should be scalar though.

Since we have no idea what you are trying to do (and your code is not exactly an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks. How can I reconcile these two (i.e mult and B) so that 'mult' will be useful in "Pr = Pr_n.*[ones(length(Xu),length(Xs)) repmat(mult,length(Xu),1)];" and subsequent lines? Also Bebs commented that error occured earlier on at "Total_Coord = [Xs Ys ones(size(Xs)) Xm Ym 2*ones(size(Xm))]; " which I never encountered. Thanks all.

Comment: Do you know what the code is supposed to do? It seems someone tossed it to you and just should just run it. That's not going to work, you need to understand what it means. You're asking how you can change it so that it will be useful. The honest answer is that we have no idea since we don't know what any of the quantities `Pr`, `Pn`, `mult` or `B` really *means*. As long was we don't know that we could suggest anything. Replace `B = [0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1];` by `B = 0.2;`. The error will disappear. Does this make sense? I don't know, probably not...